# Count field based on condition in other field

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to create a Tableau calculated field. Can someone help me rewrite the following code so that it uses the correct syntax?

```
COUNT([Type of Event]
IF(CONTAINS([Name of Event], "CANCELLED") = false) 
THEN 1 END)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write this to count that field (instead of 1), but you would get the same result - UNLESS - you did a count distinct:

```
// Normal Count
COUNT(IF CONTAINS([Name of Event],"CANCELLED") = FALSE THEN [Type of Event] END)

// Count Distinct
COUNTD(IF CONTAINS([Name of Event],"CANCELLED") = FALSE THEN [Type of Event] END)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following syntax ended up working:

```
COUNT( IF not CONTAINS([Name of Event], "CANCELLED") then [Type of Event]   END )
```